# Configuración en MySQL Server

Tags: mysql

Tengo una duda en la configuración de **MySQL Server**. 
Configure una conexión local para un proyecto con **localhost** y **3306** como `port`, sin contraseña y con usuario **root**.

Ahora tengo otro proyecto que también usa **MySQL Server**. 
Pude crear la conexión, también es con **root** como usuario pero esta vez es con contraseña. Sin embargo al tener **localhost** y **3306** por defecto, me inicia a la anterior base de datos.

¿Como puedo crear una nueva instancia?

¿Que tendría que poner en `HostName`?.

El port debe ser **3306** porque es el que inicia con **Apache**, hay problemas que sea el mismo `port` para ambos proyectos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea un usuario con otro nombre en la instancia mysql con contraseña y añade otra base de datos. No se pueden tener usuarios con el mismo nombre.

Ejemplo:

```
CREATE USER 'root2'@'localhost';
```

Para darle privilegios sobre la bbdd:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON nombreBaseDeDatos.* To 'root2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'contraseña';
```

Comment: Entre a la otra base de datos que tenia creada para realizar esos comandos... pero no se muy bien que es lo que estoy haciendo. Como sabe la base de datos que para la bdd esa use esa contraseña si aun no cree esa  bdd?

Comment: Crea esa base de datos primero con el usuario root sin contraseña...